# Statements Are Printing When Using"NOT IN"

Tags: python, sql-server

I am going crazy as to why all my if statements are printing. I am stating in my if statements that if the substring "FPL", "FCG", "GP" are not in index 5 then dont print whats in the If statement. Not sure what else to do. I have tried removing rps_table[5] with rps_table but no luck. I have also tried using the any("GP"), any("FCG") function. I am trying to check if 'FPL', FCG' or 'GP' are not in my rps_table

rps_table:

```
5412, "Test", "Test2", "test3", "test4","FPLec_4047"
5412, "Test", "Test2", "test3", "test4","FCGec_4047"
5412, "Test", "Test2", "test3", "test4","GPec_4047"
```

print rps_table[5] output:

```
GPec_SAP_235
FCGec_125
FPLec_4047
```

code:

```
    cd = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
    cd = cd.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

    rps_table_q_2 = f"""select * from test where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%ICL%' """
    rps_table_results = sql_server_cursor.execute(rps_table_q_2).fetchall()

    for rps_table in rps_table_results:
        print(rps_table[5])
        if 'GP' not in rps_table[5]:
            html_body ="File 1 Missing"
            print(html_body)
            html_body_l.append(html_body)
        if 'FCG' not in rps_table[5]:
            html_body = "File 2 Missing"
            print(html_body)
            html_body_l.append(html_body)
        if 'FPL' not in rps_table[5]:
            html_body ="File 3 Missing"
            print(html_body)
            html_body_l.append(html_body)
```

results:

```
File 1 Missing
File 2 Missing
File 3 Missing
```

Comment: Your output is incomplete, what does `print(rps_table[5])` print in each case?

Comment: @Selcuk hi, its in the "table" block. Its the 5th position of all 3 rows. GPec_SAP_235,
FCGec_125,
FPLec_4047

Comment: Please edit your question and post the whole output verbatim.

Comment: Row 1 doesn't have `FCG`  or `FPL` so you'll get those messages when processing that row.

Comment: @Barmarim trying to check if 'FPL', FCG' or 'GP' are not in my rps_table.

Comment: It looks like you expect `if 'FPL' not in rps_table[5]` to find items that contain `FPL` as a _substring_, but it doesn't do that.  It will only find `FPL` as a whole exact item, which is not present.

Comment: @JohnGordon Is there a way to find substring then? i thought that statement would find 'FPL' inside my output 'FPLec_4047' and not execute the print.

Comment: @JohnGordon That's not true. `substring in string` looks for a substring.

Comment: `rps_table` is a row, `rps_table[5]` is one column in the row.

Comment: @Barmar From the output, it looked to me like `rps_table[5]` was not a single string, but a list of strings.  Perhaps I misinterpreted the formatting.

Comment: The script is printing it each time through the loop. Each one is a different row.

Comment: Ahh, I see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you process each row of results, you're checking it for all 3 types of data. But it will only match one of them, and you'll print "missing" messages for the other two.

Instead, loop over the different prefixes and check all the rows for them.

```
required_prefixes = ['GP', 'FCG', 'FPL']
for i, prefix in enumerate(required_prefixes, 1):
    if not any(row[5].startswith(prefix) for row in rps_table_results):
        html_body = f'File {i} missing'
        print(html_body)
        html_body_l.append(html_body)
```

I've also changed from `in` to `.startswith()` since it looks like the strings you're searching for are always at the beginning of the column.

Comment: Thank you!!! can you briefly explain what i was doing wrong? Was it because i was searching for "GP" when the "GP" row wasnt being iterated over?

Comment: Right. On each line you're checking for every prefix. But a line can only have one prefix.